# Why does this JavaScript css filter code work in Firefox but not in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox

The filters work in unison in Firefox (43.0.1), but not in Chrome (57.0.2987.133). In Chrome, when I move my mouse over another slider, the previous slider's adjustments are removed. There is a similar question regarding image filters, but it does apply to the Firefox vs. Chrome issue.

```css
var degrees=0;
var percentB=100;
var percentC=100;
function setValues() {
  form1.brightness.value=100;
  form1.contrast.value=100;
  form1.hue.value=0;
}

function bright() {
  percentB=form1.brightness.value;
  document.getElementById("I").style.filter="brightness("+parseInt(percentB)+"%)"+" contrast("+parseInt(percentC)+"%)"+" hue-rotate("+parseInt(degrees)+"deg)";
}

function cont() {
  percentC=form1.contrast.value;
  document.getElementById("I").style.filter="brightness("+parseInt(percentB)+"%)"+" contrast("+parseInt(percentC)+"%)"+" hue-rotate("+parseInt(degrees)+"deg)";
}

function hues() {
  degrees=form1.hue.value;
  document.getElementById("I").style.filter="brightness("+parseInt(percentB)+"%)"+" contrast("+parseInt(percentC)+"%)"+" hue-rotate("+parseInt(degrees)+"deg)";
}
```

```html
<img src="xbutterfly.jpg" alt="Colorful Flowers" width="800" height="533" id="I" /><br><br>

<form name="form1" id="form1id" style="font-size:90%; text-align:center;">
  Brightness: <input type="range" name="brightness" min="0" max="200" step="5" onmousemove="bright()" style="vertical-align:-7px;" />&nbsp; &nbsp; Contrast: <input type="range" name="contrast" min="0" max="200" step="5" onmousemove="cont()" style="vertical-align:-7px;"
  />&nbsp; &nbsp; Hue: <input type="range" name="hue" min="0" max="360" step="5" onmousemove="hues()" style="vertical-align:-7px;" />
</form>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/anzhdjnt/ It works on my FF & Chrome

Comment: which version of chorome are you using?

Comment: Works on my chrome Chrome (57.0.2987.133) https://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/4z8zmd7c/1/ example

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your input!  Additional comments are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fighting with this for 2 hours, I finally saw a solution after posting the question: combining everything into one function.

New HTML:

```
   <img src="xbutterfly.jpg" alt="Colorful Flowers" width="800" height="533" id="I" /><br><br>  
   <form name="form1" id="form1id" style="font-size:90%; text-align:center;">
    Brightness: <input type="range" name="brightness" min="0" max="200" step="5" onmousemove="apply()" style="vertical-align:-7px;" />&nbsp; &nbsp;
    Contrast: <input type="range" name="contrast" min="0" max="200" step="5" onmousemove="apply()" style="vertical-align:-7px;"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    Hue: <input type="range" name="hue" min="0" max="360" step="5" onmousemove="apply()" style="vertical-align:-7px;"/> 
   </form>
```

New JavaScript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--

  var degrees = 0;
  var percentB = 100; 
  var percentC = 100;

  function setValues()
  {      
    form1.brightness.value = 100;
    form1.contrast.value = 100;
    form1.hue.value = 0;      
  }

  function apply()
  { 
    degrees = form1.hue.value;
    percentC = form1.contrast.value;
    percentB = form1.brightness.value;  
    document.getElementById("I").style.filter = "brightness(" + parseInt(percentB) + "%)" + " contrast(" + parseInt(percentC) + "%)" + " hue-rotate(" + parseInt(degrees) + "deg)";   
    document.getElementById("I").style.WebkitFilter = "brightness(" + parseInt(percentB) + "%)" + " contrast(" + parseInt(percentC) + "%)" + " hue-rotate(" + parseInt(degrees) + "deg)"; // Not tested as I don't have these browsers. Used for older versions of Safari, Chrome, and Opera per https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_filter.asp  
  }

  --> 
  </script>
```